# Wrapping C++ struct template in SWIG

Tags: c++, templates, struct, swig

I have a C++ code that wraps an existing Object with a probability as follows:

```
template< typename Object > struct Roll
{
    Object object;          
    double probability; 

    Roll( Object p, double s )
        : object( p )
        , probability( s )
    { }
}
```

Later, this will be defined in the same .h file as:

```
typedef Roll< Color > RollColor;
```

There's instruction around how to wrap a C++ struct with primitive type in SWIG but this one has something to do with the template also, so I don't know how to wrap it properly in my interface file. Do you have any idea how can I do this ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

In the `.i` file, use:

```
%template(RollColor) Roll<Color>;
```

More info at http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn26.

Assuming you have the template defined in `roll.h` and `Color` is defined in `color.h`, you will need to use:

```
%{
   #include "roll.h"
   #include "color.h"
%}

#include "roll.h"
#include "color.h"

%template(RollColor) Roll<Color>;
```

**Update, in response to OP's comment**

You can use:

```
%template(RollColors) std::vector<Roll<Color>>;
```

However, you will need to implement a default constructor in `Roll` first. Without that you can't create a `std::vector` of `Roll<T>`s.

You can use

```
%template(RollColors) std::vector<RollColor>;
```

only if you have a C++ typedef.

```
%{
   #include "roll.h"
   #include "color.h"
   typedef Roll<Color> RollColor;
%}
```

Comment: When compiling it gave me error "Template 'Roll' undefined" , although the header Roll.h has already been included in my interface file

Comment: Hi, so bad I can't give an upvote yet due to lack of reputation point, but surely I'll get back later ;). Is this also possible to use a template in other template like %template(RollColors) std::vector<RollColor>, or I have to use %template(RollColors) std::vector<Roll<Color>> ? Because this one gave me error due to Roll() initialization